# F# combine float list to a float

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and I'm struggling to figure out how I could combine the numbers in a float list to a float.

If I have the list

`let floatList = [ 9.0; 8.0; 3.0 ]`

I would like a function where the return value is a float of value 983.0. How would I go about this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You go through the list, multiply the previously accumulated number by 10, then add the current element of the list:

```
((9 * 10) + 8) * 10 + 3 = 983
```

A handy way to go through the list while keeping an "accumulator" is [`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5b%27t%2c%27state%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
floatList
|> List.fold (fun acc n -> acc*10 + n) 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain `rev`, `mapi`(map with index) and `sum` functions

```
let digits = [| 9.0; 8.0; 3.0 |]
let result = 
    Array.rev digits 
    |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> x * (10.0 ** float i)) 
    |> Array.sum

printfn "%f" result
```

Because array can return it's length without iterating over the collection, you can remove "reversing" and calculate offset for power based on the index and length

```
let digits = [| 9.0; 8.0; 3.0 |]

let result = 
  Array.mapi (fun i x -> x * (10.0 ** float (digits.Length - i))) digits
  |> Array.sum

printfn "%f" result
```

Comment: You are right for arrays, but for lists calculating length is indeed O(n)

Comment: Check out [the source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/24c798bfcee5d6f91ae2c19888baeb9946744c3a/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3194)

Answer (score -1):

This is a way to do it

```
let floatList = [ 9.0; 8.0; 3.0 ]
let rec loop mult list =
    match list with
    | head :: tail -> (mult * head) + (loop (mult / 10.) tail)
    | [] -> 0.

let mult = 10. ** float ((List.length floatList) - 1) // len 1 = 1. len 2 = 10. len 3 = 100
let result = loop mult floatList
printfn "%f" result
```